# How to get a 2D floor plan with dimensions from USDZ file RoomPlan 3D model ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, roomplan

Tried the following link

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713409

but could'nt succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating spritekit project and using the following link was able to achieve the task

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713409